# Hibernate maps with discrimination column or class name as key

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, one-to-many

I've been pulling my hair out over this for the best part of a day now, and simply can't find any answers to this problem.

I've got a PostgreSQL schems that looks like this:

```
 +---------+   1-n   +-------------+   1-1   +------+
 | Product |-------->| ProductSpec |-------->| Spec |
 +---------+         +-------------+         +------+
```

This represents a one to many relationship between a Product and its list of Specifications (The reason I don't just use a foreign key in the specifications table into the products table is because specifications can belong to things that aren't in the product inheritance tree, those links are represented by other intersection tables).

Each Specification is a subclass of a Specification class (Weight, Length, NumberOfThings, and so on), with the name of the subclass in question being stored in the Spec table.  Each product has a collection of specifications, but each subclass of specification can only appear once.  A product can only have one weight (though if you need a weight for the actual product, and a shipping weight for the courier to calculate shipping charges, you can simply subclass ActualWeight and ShippingWeight from the Weight specification).

Using the simplest case, a Set in the Product class, I'm able to construct the object graph correctly from a Hibernate query of the products table.  I want to use a Map instead, however, so I can address specific specifications directly.  The plan was to use the class name as the key, but I'm having serious issues trying to get it to work.  I'm unable to figure out how to use the Java class name as the key, and trying to use the class name as stored in the database as the map key is proving problematic.

As currently implemented, I'm able to query the specifications, and the products individually (if I comment out the code implementing the mapping between products and specifications).  I can also query the products with the specifications embedded if I use a set, but if I use a map with the MapKey set to be the specifications class name, I get an exception.

> Sep 01, 2013 1:25:55 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter
>   logExceptions WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01 Sep 01, 2013
>   1:25:55 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
>   SEVERE: ERROR: relation "specifications" does not exist Position: 424

I've annotated my (cut down) classes as follows.  The product class:

```
@Entity
@Table (
        name="products",
        schema="sellable"
)
public abstract class Product extends Sellable {
    private Map <String, Specification> specifications  = new HashMap <> ();

    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade (CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @JoinTable (
        schema = "sellable",
        name = "productspecifications", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "sll_id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "spc_id")})
    @MapKey (name = "className")
    private Map <String, Specification> getSpecifications () {
        return this.specifications;
    }

    private Product setSpecifications (Map <String, Specification> specs) {
        this.specifications = specs;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the Specification class:

```
@Entity
@Table (
        name="specifications",
        schema="sellable",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint (columnNames="spc_id") 
)
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn (name = "spc_classname", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Specification implements Serializable {
    private Integer specId      = null;
    private String  className   = null;

    @Id
    @Column (name="spc_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @SequenceGenerator (name = "specifications_spc_id_seq", sequenceName = "sellable.specifications_spc_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "specifications_spc_id_seq")
    public Integer getSpecId () {
        return this.specId;
    }

    private Specification setSpecId (Integer specId) {
        this.specId = specId;
        return this;
    }

    @Column (name="spc_classname", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public String getClassName () {
        return this.className;
    }

    private void setClassName (String className) {
        this.className  = className;
    }
}
```

The DB schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sellable.sellables
(
  sll_id serial NOT NULL, -- Sellable ID
  sll_date_created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), -- Date the item was created
  sll_date_updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), -- Date the item was last updated
  sll_title character varying(255) NOT NULL, -- Title of the item
  sll_desc text NOT NULL, -- Textual description of the item
  CONSTRAINT sellables_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sll_id)
)

CREATE TABLE sellable.products
(
  sll_id integer NOT NULL, -- Sellable ID
  mfr_id integer NOT NULL, -- ID of the product manufacturer
  CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sll_id),
  CONSTRAINT products_mfr_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (mfr_id)
      REFERENCES sellable.manufacturers (mfr_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT products_sll_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sll_id)
      REFERENCES sellable.sellables (sll_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE sellable.specifications
(
  spc_id serial NOT NULL, -- Specification ID
  spc_classname character varying(127) NOT NULL, -- Specification subclass
  CONSTRAINT specifications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (spc_id)
)

CREATE TABLE sellable.productspecifications
(
  ps_id serial NOT NULL, -- Primary key
  sll_id integer NOT NULL, -- Product the specification is linked to
  spc_id integer NOT NULL, -- Specification the product is associated with
  CONSTRAINT productspecifications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ps_id),
  CONSTRAINT productspecifications_sll_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sll_id)
      REFERENCES sellable.products (sll_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT productspecifications_spc_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (spc_id)
      REFERENCES sellable.specifications (spc_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT productspecifications_spc_id_key UNIQUE (spc_id)
)
```

The query that Hibernate generates is listed below (I've not trimmed this the way I have the classes in case there's something in the unabridged query that is an issue).  One obvious problem is that it's trying to query the specifications table without inserting the schema name.

```
select
    bicycle0_.sll_id as sll1_0_3_,
    bicycle0_2_.sll_date_created as sll2_0_3_,
    bicycle0_2_.sll_date_updated as sll3_0_3_,
    bicycle0_2_.sll_desc as sll4_0_3_,
    bicycle0_2_.sll_title as sll5_0_3_,
    bicycle0_1_.mfr_id as mfr2_1_3_,
    bicycle0_.btp_id as btp2_2_3_,
    manufactur1_.mfr_id as mfr1_4_0_,
    manufactur1_.mfr_name as mfr2_4_0_,
    specificat2_.sll_id as sll1_5_,
    specificat3_.spc_id as spc2_5_,
    (select
        a9.spc_classname 
    from
        specifications a9 
    where
        a9.spc_id=specificat2_.spc_id) as formula0_5_,
    specificat3_.spc_id as spc2_5_1_,
    specificat3_.spc_classname as spc1_5_1_,
    specificat3_1_.dec_value as dec1_6_1_,
    specificat3_2_.bol_value as bol1_7_1_,
    specificat3_3_.int_value as int1_8_1_,
    specificat3_4_.str_value as str1_9_1_,
    bicycletyp4_.btp_id as btp1_3_2_,
    bicycletyp4_.btp_name as btp2_3_2_ 
from
    sellable.bicycles bicycle0_ 
inner join
    sellable.products bicycle0_1_ 
        on bicycle0_.sll_id=bicycle0_1_.sll_id 
inner join
    sellable.sellables bicycle0_2_ 
        on bicycle0_.sll_id=bicycle0_2_.sll_id 
left outer join
    sellable.manufacturers manufactur1_ 
        on bicycle0_1_.mfr_id=manufactur1_.mfr_id 
left outer join
    sellable.productspecifications specificat2_ 
        on bicycle0_.sll_id=specificat2_.sll_id 
left outer join
    sellable.specifications specificat3_ 
        on specificat2_.spc_id=specificat3_.spc_id 
left outer join
    sellable.specdecimalvalues specificat3_1_ 
        on specificat3_.spc_id=specificat3_1_.spc_id 
left outer join
    sellable.specbooleanvalues specificat3_2_ 
        on specificat3_.spc_id=specificat3_2_.spc_id 
left outer join
    sellable.specintegervalues specificat3_3_ 
        on specificat3_.spc_id=specificat3_3_.spc_id 
left outer join
    sellable.specstringvalues specificat3_4_ 
        on specificat3_.spc_id=specificat3_4_.spc_id 
left outer join
    sellable.bicycletypes bicycletyp4_ 
        on bicycle0_.btp_id=bicycletyp4_.btp_id 
where
    bicycle0_.sll_id=?
```

The problem is in the sub-query, which isn't getting a schema prepended to the specifications table name.

If anyone knows how to either get the query to be correct, or of using the class name directly as the Java map key, I'd appreciate being told.

EDIT: The reason I want to use a map instead of a set is because I want to directly address items in the specifications collection.  If I use sets, the queries generated by Hibernate work, but I don't have an index to access the elements by.  The API of the Product object hides the fact that the specifications are stored in a collection and provides getters and setters for each individual specification.

If I make the specifications a set, I have to implement the getters and setters like this:

```
@Transient
public BigDecimal getActualWeight () {
    BigDecimal  found   = null;
    for (Specification spec : this.specifications) {
        if (spec instanceof ActualWeightSpec) {
            found   = ((ActualWeightSpec) spec).getValue ();
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

public Product setActualWeight (Number value) {
    ActualWeightSpec newWeight  = new ActualWeightSpec ();
    newWeight.setValue (value);

    for (Specification spec : this.specifications) {
        if (spec instanceof ActualWeightSpec) {
            ((ActualWeightSpec) spec).setValue (value);
            return this;
        }
    }

    this.specifications.add (newWeight);
    return this;
}
```

Having to iterate over a set to get individual specification records seems a really bad way of accessing those records directly.

I did try maintaining a hashmap internally, and having the getter and setter for the specifications accept and return sets with a conversion taking place in the getter and setter.  That way I'd only have to take the hit of iterating the specifications once.

```
private Product setSpecifications (Set <Specification> specs) {
    HashMap <String, Specification> specsMap = new HashMap <> ();

    for (Specification spec : specs) {
        specsMap.put(spec.getClassName (), spec);
    }

    this.specifications = specsMap;
    return this;
}
```

This didn't work either, causing Hibernate to throw an exception.

> SEVERE: illegal access to loading collection

Comment: Not so sure this will help you, your setup is pretty complex and I can't duplicate your system easily.
<br>
<br> "if I use a set, but if I use a map with the MapKey set to be the specifications class name, I get an exception."
<br>
What's so special about a set, such that it'll work but not a "non-unique" mapkey?
<br>
Next, what's with the error message? What's on line 424?

Comment: I think it's actually position 424 of the generated SQL

Comment: You wrote this, " (The reason I don't just use a foreign key in the specifications table into the products table is because specifications can belong to things that aren't in the product inheritance tree, those links are represented by other intersection tables)."  And you're trying to normalize the specifications table, right? Can you split the specifications into product_tree_specifications and out_of_tree_specifications ??

Comment: I suppose I could, but then I'd have two essentially identical classes on the Java side whose only real differentiator was that one belonged to one type of object and the other to a different type.  The fact that the Specification class is subclassed for the various datatypes complicates things further.

Comment: so what does the error message, "relation doesn't exist", mean? You're trying to join with sll_id and spc_id but there is no spc_id in products and no sll_id in specifications...

Comment: `REFERENCES sellable.specifications (spc_id) MATCH SIMPLE`, don't you have to make spc_id unique for the relation to occur? shouldn't that match the constraint, specifications_pkey instead of spc_id? (I'm about to give up, cause I doubt that I'm helping you much...)

Comment: Ok, I checked the postgres manual. I still don't see where your table declarations stipulate that spc_id is UNIQUE. I do see where the table constraint specifications_pkey is though. Does the table need a column constraint so that hibernate can map a class to the rows? From the postgres manual,

Comment: `5.3.5. Foreign Keys

A foreign key constraint specifies that the values in a column (or a group of columns) must match the values appearing in some row of another table. We say this maintains the referential integrity between two related tables.` i.e. the creates the relation. But you are using a table constraint instead of a column constraint...?

Comment: sellable.specifications instead.

Comment: spc_id is the primary key of the specifications table which makes it unique by definition.  In the productspecifications intersection table, there's a unique constraint on the spc_id foreign key. `CONSTRAINT productspecifications_spc_id_key UNIQUE (spc_id)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the table definitions are correct, though if a postgres expert can spot a mistake in them then I'm obviously open to suggestions on that front.  The problem appears to be that Hibernate generates an incorrect query.  It includes a subquery that addresses `specifications` instead of `sellable.specifications` and because the default schema isn't sellable it fails because it can't find the specifications table.  This is in spte of `sellable.specifcations` being addressed in the outer query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a internal map of specifications, not bothering the database with the map. Do not initialize the map in getters or setters Hibernate uses, but check in your getters (e.g. `getActualWeight`) if your transient map has been initialized already. If not, iterate the specs once and build the map. Btw, if there are not too many specs, iterating each time should not hurt too much.

Comment: I've pretty much already implemented an approach along those lines.  It appears to work okay, but it feels a bit inelegant.  Hibernate ought to be able to do this without having to mess around like that!

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Not sure about the inelegance of the approach: The map you are using is more about efficient data access and not required for a "nice" relational data structure.